# DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application for NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, installation, anaconda

I downloaded NumPy through Anaconda and copied and pasted the NumPy file from there to the site-package file in the Python 27 folder.

I was trying to import NumPy from a 2.7.5 shell, and it gave me an error:

> DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I tried to research ways to get around it like verifying that I downloaded the right version (64-bit, Python 2.7) and even tried downloading it again, but it still gave me the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
import numpy
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded NumPy through Anaconda and **copied and pasted the NumPy file from there to the site-package file in the Python 27 folder**.

Don't do this! [Follow the instructions on the Continuum website](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#windows-install) and install using the `.exe` file.

Anaconda is a fully self-contained environment that includes its own installers for Python - you don't need to do anything to your system-wide `site-packages` directory.

Comment: I tried to download the installer and tried to import numpy again on the command line, but it still did not work. I even tried typing in the command on the command prompt, but "Anaconda-2.x.x-Windows-x86[_64].exe" was not recognized. When I tried to remove the copied Numpy from the Python27 folder, it tells me "No module named numpy"

Comment: @Vanstorm My guess is that you're not launching the correct Python executable. There should be a `python27.exe` in a subdirectory of your Anaconda installation directory - in Mac or Linux it would be in `/path/to/anaconda/bin/python`, but I don't have a Windows machine at hand to check the exact location. You need to start this local version of Python, **not** the system-wide one in `C:\Python27\\``. I'd also highly recommend you use the `ipython` rather than the plain `python` shell, which Anaconda also comes with.

Comment: I managed to open up the command line of python.exe in the Anaconda folder. However whenever I type in this code: "Anaconda-2.x.x-Windows-x86[_64].exe", it's telling me that Anaconda is not defined. Something like this: http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2014/08/16/140816054554134511.png  Any idea on what the problem is?

Comment: @Vanstorm You're looking for a **Python** executable, e.g. `C:\Anaconda\python.exe` (I'm not sure of the exact path). FYI, when you reply to someone else's comment use '@theirname' at the start so that they'll get a notification that you've replied.